# Is there a way to specify the title of a job from mrjob in the Hadoop Administration web interface?

Tags: python, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, mrjob

I have several different jobs started from the Python library [mrjob](https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob), including jobs with multiple steps. How can I replace `streamjob` with a custom name? For example, `wordcount_step_1`, `wordcount_step_2`, etc.

[image: screenshot of Hadoop Administration]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just specify it using the [--jobconf](http://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/guides/configs-hadoopy-runners.html) option when you execute your job.

For example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Be careful, this appends all job args, if you have lots it could be a problem
    sys.argv.extend(["--jobconf", "mapred.job.name=%s" % " ".join(sys.argv)])
    MRYourJobClass.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

When running the job add the option:

```
--jobconf mapred.job.name=NameOfTheJob
```